# Calculate area between 2 curves when you know only their data points

Tags: integration, area, curves

How can I calculate the area between 2 curves when I only have their data points and the points are united with lines ( linear)

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please give us your thoughts about your problem and some precisions to better understand what you need.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the area between 2 curves in general?

Answer (score 0):

You find the numerical approximation to your integral.

For each $x$, find $|y_1 -y_2|$  and use Trapezoidal or Simpson rule to approximate the area.

Comment: This gives the unsigned area. The most direct analogue to a definite integral would be to find the signed area, and for that, you shouldn't use the absolute value. It depends on what exactly is required.

Comment: Sure,  you may find the signed area but usually the area  between two curves is found by integrating the positive difference.